# Mac app-UIImage and CGSize replacment

Tags: macos

I have a class (for iOS) that takes images from the internet and manipulates them.
I'm trying to get it to work on Mac (OSX), but after importing, I'm getting errors.

I need the Mac equivalent for the following lines (e.g UIImage=NSImage)

```
1.  NSImage *image = [NSImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgurl]];(image with data)

2.  NSValue *value=[NSValue valueWithCGSize:imgsize];  (value with size)

3.  CGSize rect1 = [[obj1 valueForKey:@"size"] CGSizeValue];(cgsize value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use the NSRect? NSRect is equivalent of CGRect.
Here's the solution:

```
1. NSImage *aImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]];
2. CGRect rc;
NSValue* rcValue = [NSValue valueWithRect:*(NSRect*)&rc];
3. NSRect rc1 = [rcValue rectValue];
CGRect rc2 = *(CGRect*)&rc1;
```

PS:CGRect to a NSRect by doing this: NSRect nsrc = *(NSRect*)&cgrc;